# VS Code on Mac Using C++ Debugger Not Working Properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am having an odd issue. I am working in C++ and I have coderunner installed and the basic C/C++ extension from Microsoft, but I am having an issue with my debugger.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> numbers{10,20,30,40,50};
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << numbers[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At the moment hit Run Code it runes just fine displaying the output I was expecting, but when I run the debugger I choose g++. This is what displays in the debug console:
[image]
But I still have a problem listed as:

```
vec.cpp:7:24: error: expected ';' at end of declaration

    vector<int> numbers{10,20,30,40,50};
                       ^
                       ;

1 error generated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

It seems to be running an older version of C++, but my configurations are as list

```
    "C_Cpp_Runner.cCompilerPath": "clang",
    "C_Cpp_Runner.cppCompilerPath": "clang++",
    "C_Cpp_Runner.cppStandard": "c++17",
    "C_Cpp_Runner.cStandard": "c17",
    "C_Cpp_Runner.debuggerPath": "lldb",
    "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++17",
    "C_Cpp.default.cStandard": "c17",
    // "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome",
    "code-runner.executorMap":{
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    }
```

Any ideas on why this would happen? Really confused why it would execute in the debug console, but not in the debugger. My compilers, g++ and clang++ are both up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler supports **C++11** standards then `vector<int> numbers{1, 2, 3};` can be used.

You should not get this error when you try the following usage:

```cpp
std::vector<int> numbers;

numbers.push_back(10);
numbers.push_back(20);
numbers.push_back(30);
numbers.push_back(40);
numbers.push_back(50);
```

If you are using **Clang** compiler you should use the following command to compile:

```sh
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ vec.cpp
```

You can learn about the `clang++` command's options by reading the "[Clang Command Line Reference](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html)".